# What is the difference between an Endpoints service and AppEngine service when they have the same URL?

Tags: rest, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I have two services in Endpoints in GCP to host two APIs

They are

Service A

and

Service B

Service A's host is
projectid.appspot.com

Service B's host is 
test-dot-projectid.appspot.com

When I deploy my app using gcloud app deploy Service A's test service in 
appengine my app.yaml looks like this

```
runtime: go
env: flex
service: test

endpoints_api_service:
  name: projectid.appspot.com
  rollout_strategy: managed

handlers:
- url: .*  #mandatory
  secure: always  #deprecated in flex environment
  redirect_http_response_code: 301 #optional
  script: _go_app #mandatory
```

From my understanding, the app has been deployed to Service A's URL
projectid.appspot.com but with the subdomain test so test-dot-projectid.appspot.com

However is this now not technically deploying to Service B on a default service i.e.
test-dot-projectid.appspot.com

Is this not interfering with deploying on service A with service test? What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is: if service A is "projectid.appspot.com".  Only "projectid.appspot.com" will be routed to A,  not "test.projectid.appspot.com".  So you can safely deploy sevice B with "test.projectid.appspot.com".  But I am not sure.  Have you tried it?

Comment: I find if I deploy service A to test.projectid.appspot.com (i.e. by enabling the test service) it uses service A's configuration (for example, the security key is enabled in A not service B). If I deploy to service B while enabling test service it uses service B's configuration (e.g. security key is not enabled on B).

Comment: Even though the URL for service A is  "projectid.appspot.com" I can use it on the test service where the URL is "test.projectid.appspot.com". Likewise service B's URL is "test.projectid.appspot.com" and I can also use it on the test service where the URL is "test.projectid.appspot.com". I want to see what happens when I change the service name to test1 and deploy service A and service B, I feel like the host name in endpoints is almost irrelevant to the URL

Answer (score 0):

When having an application with multiple services, the service names must be configured and must be unique.

The default project is not required to have a service name. This is true when a single service for an application exists.

When having multiple services (Service A, Service B), the application must be first deployed to the default service. After which, each service must have their own app.yaml file.

It is recommended for each service to be configured with a unique service name to prevent miscommunication. If a unique service name is not configured for each service, by default, it will deploy to the default service’s URL.  In your case, since the default service URL and Service A’s service URL are the same, it is causing a conflict.

To deploy to a specific services’ service name, you will need to specify the service name and its app.yaml file.

For more information, please refer to:

Planning your directory structure and app.yaml naming:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/configuration-files#directory_structure

How to deploy to multiple or specific service in a multi-service environment:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/testing-and-deploying-your-app#deploying_multiple_services

Comment: I'm reading this but I feel like the word service is so ambiguous, does it mean appengine service or endpoints service D: When it says multiple services does it mean multiple endpoint services? that's what service A and B are

Answer (score 0):

App Engine is made up of application resources that are made up of one or more services (previously known as modules). Each service is code independent and can run different runtimes and you deploy versions of that service. The URL is how your application is accessed either via a user request or an API call to the service.

For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine#app_engine_services_as_microservices

Endpoints are part of the Cloud Endpoints Framework service offered by Google Cloud to manage, deploy, maintain and secure your API. In App Engine, Endpoint framework is only supported on Python 2.7 and Java runtime environments. It is a tool that allows you to generate REST API and client libraries for your application.

For more information, please see 
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks

Comment: User is using Flex. It is using ESP, a nginx based proxy, not frame-work.